# Lost a .service file

Tags: filesystem, services

I get an error message that a .service file is missing. I have no idea what this file is or
how it was supposed to be put there.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1423614/edit) to show us the complete, accurate wording of the entire error message. Also clearly describe the steps you take to get that error message.

Comment: We also don't know what OS/release or Ubuntu product you're using, so we needs more details to know what should be there too.